# Xcode 5 for IOS 8 apps

Tags: ios, xcode

ive just started to Learn to program and write code in objective C, i want to be making iphone apps/games. Im currently stuck with an old iMac that cannot run Mavericks therefore cannot run Xcode 6. So my question is, can i make IOS 8 apps in Xcode 5? Thanks!

Comment: No, you will need Xcode 6 and maverick to use the iOS 8 SDK.

Comment: It must be a very old iMac indeed, as [Mavericks runs on iMacs going back to mid-2007](http://www.everymac.com/mac-answers/os-x-10.9-mavericks-faq/os-x-mavericks-compatible-macs-system-requirements.html).

Comment: Thanks guys, yes it's 2006! Looks like I need to upgrade!

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately you can't use iOS 8 features in your development as it's available from Xcode 6 and it's SDK. Your app built with previous versions of SDK should run on latest system version when downloaded from AppStore but if you want to debug on device with iOS8 than xcode 5 will complain about your SDK.

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion: No you cant. The SDK for iOS 8 could only be installed in XCode 6.

But you could use:

[http://www.macincloud.com](http://www.macincloud.com/)